Custom spring boot starter doesn't see file
I want to write to my file from my own custom spring boot starter, but it can't see it
I tried this code in main app and in the starter
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Михаил\\IdeaProjects\\education-project\\src\\main\\resources\\animals\\logData.txt");
        System.out.println(Files.exists(path));

In main app, this writes "true", but in starter "false"
